# use pd.melt to transform columns into two separate variable-value columns

Tags: python, pandas, melt

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'A1':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'A2':[3,4,5,6,7,8], 'B1':[9,8,7,6,5,4], 'B2':[6,5,4,3,2,1], 'C':['x','x','x','y','y','y']})
```

I'm trying to melt this dataframe in this way

```
    ID  C variable1  value1 variable2  value2
     1  x       A1      1      B1       9
     2  x       A1      2      B1       8       
     3  x       A1      3      B1       7
     4  y       A1      4      B1       6
     5  y       A1      5      B1       5
     6  y       A1      6      B1       4
     1  x       A2      3      B2       6
     2  x       A2      4      B2       5
     3  x       A2      5      B2       4
     4  y       A2      6      B2       3
     5  y       A2      7      B2       2
     6  y       A2      8      B2       1
```

`pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID','C'])` will create a single variable and value column, but how can I achieve the result above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more like a `wide_to_long` problem

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['A','B'],i=['ID','C'],j='Number').reset_index()
    ID  C  Number  A  B
0    1  x       1  1  9
1    1  x       2  3  6
2    2  x       1  2  8
3    2  x       2  4  5
4    3  x       1  3  7
5    3  x       2  5  4
6    4  y       1  4  6
7    4  y       2  6  3
8    5  y       1  5  5
9    5  y       2  7  2
10   6  y       1  6  4
11   6  y       2  8  1
```

Comment: thanks @WeNYoBen, it works great (+1). However in my real dataset the variables are named like this `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'abc_tac':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'ght_tac':[3,4,5,6,7,8], 'abc_toc':[9,8,7,6,5,4], 'ght_toc':[6,5,4,3,2,1], 'C':['x','x','x','y','y','y']})` and so the "number" approach won't work. How would you deal with this case? The `tac` and `toc` being equivalent to `1` and `2` in my question

Comment: @HappyPy pass `sep='_'` and `suffix = '.*'` as arguments to `wide_to_long`

Comment: @HappyPyH I think ALollz explain and answer your question well :-)